# Vulkan. Does not record the buffer depth during the passage in shadowmap

Tags: c++, qt, vulkan

I tried to add shadows to a project using this example. (https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/tree/master/examples/shadowmapping)
Unfortunately it did not work. More precisely, it works on cleaning the buffer  depth of the first pass. But the pass itself either does not work, or does not write the depth buffer to the sampler, which I pass to the second pass. At the same time, the parameters for cleaning the depth buffer affect the sampler. I checked the transfer of the scene parameters when rendering from a light source, they are correct. I do not know what to think anymore. Perhaps somewhere a simple error that I do not understand.

first pass pipeline

```
VkPipeline MainRenderer::initShadowPipeline(const VKStr::Device & device, VkPipelineLayout pipelineLayout, VkRenderPass renderPass, std::string vShaderName)
{
    VkPipeline resultPipelineHandle = VK_NULL_HANDLE;

    std::vector<VkVertexInputBindingDescription> bindingDescription = GetVertexInputBindingDescriptions(0);
    std::vector<VkVertexInputAttributeDescription> attributeDescriptions = GetVertexInputAttributeDescriptions(0);

    VkPipelineVertexInputStateCreateInfo vertexInputStage = {};
    vertexInputStage.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VERTEX_INPUT_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    vertexInputStage.vertexBindingDescriptionCount = (uint32_t)bindingDescription.size();
    vertexInputStage.pVertexBindingDescriptions = bindingDescription.data();
    vertexInputStage.vertexAttributeDescriptionCount = (uint32_t)attributeDescriptions.size();
    vertexInputStage.pVertexAttributeDescriptions = attributeDescriptions.data();

    VkPipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo inputAssemblyStage = {};
    inputAssemblyStage.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_INPUT_ASSEMBLY_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    inputAssemblyStage.topology = VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLE_LIST;          
    inputAssemblyStage.primitiveRestartEnable = VK_FALSE;                       

    std::vector<VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo> shaderStages = {
        {
            VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO,
            nullptr,
            0,
            VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT,
            LoadSPIRVShader(vShaderName, device.logicalDevice),
            "main",
            nullptr
        }
    };

    VkViewport viewport = {};
    viewport.width = (float)shadowPass_.width;
    viewport.height = (float)shadowPass_.height;
    viewport.minDepth = 0.0f;
    viewport.maxDepth = 1.0f;

    VkRect2D scissor = {};
    scissor.offset = { 0, 0 };
    scissor.extent.width = shadowPass_.width;
    scissor.extent.height = shadowPass_.height;

    VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo viewportState = {};
    viewportState.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VIEWPORT_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    viewportState.viewportCount = 1;
    viewportState.pViewports = &viewport;
    viewportState.scissorCount = 1;
    viewportState.pScissors = &scissor;
    viewportState.flags = 0;

    VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo rasterizationStage = {};
    rasterizationStage.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_RASTERIZATION_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    rasterizationStage.depthClampEnable = VK_FALSE;                                 
    rasterizationStage.polygonMode = VK_POLYGON_MODE_FILL;            
    rasterizationStage.lineWidth = 1.0f;                              
    rasterizationStage.cullMode = VK_CULL_MODE_BACK_BIT;                
    rasterizationStage.frontFace = VK_FRONT_FACE_COUNTER_CLOCKWISE;
    rasterizationStage.depthBiasEnable = VK_TRUE;                     
    rasterizationStage.depthBiasConstantFactor = 1.25f;
    rasterizationStage.depthBiasClamp = 0.0f;
    rasterizationStage.depthBiasSlopeFactor = 1.75f;

    VkPipelineDepthStencilStateCreateInfo depthStencilStage = {};
    depthStencilStage.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_DEPTH_STENCIL_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    depthStencilStage.depthTestEnable = VK_TRUE;
    depthStencilStage.depthWriteEnable = VK_TRUE;
    depthStencilStage.depthCompareOp = VK_COMPARE_OP_LESS_OR_EQUAL;
    depthStencilStage.back.compareOp = VK_COMPARE_OP_ALWAYS;
    depthStencilStage.front = depthStencilStage.back;

    VkPipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo multisamplingStage = {};
    multisamplingStage.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_MULTISAMPLE_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    multisamplingStage.rasterizationSamples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;  
    multisamplingStage.flags = 0;

    VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState colorBlendAttachment = {};
    colorBlendAttachment.colorWriteMask = 0xf;
    colorBlendAttachment.blendEnable = VK_FALSE;

    VkPipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo colorBlendState = {};
    colorBlendState.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_COLOR_BLEND_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    colorBlendState.attachmentCount = 0;
    colorBlendState.pAttachments = &colorBlendAttachment;

    std::vector<VkDynamicState> dynamicStateEnables = { VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_VIEWPORT, VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_SCISSOR };
    dynamicStateEnables.push_back(VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_DEPTH_BIAS);

    VkPipelineDynamicStateCreateInfo dynamicStateCI = {};
    dynamicStateCI.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_DYNAMIC_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    dynamicStateCI.pDynamicStates = dynamicStateEnables.data();
    dynamicStateCI.dynamicStateCount = dynamicStateEnables.size();
    dynamicStateCI.flags = 0;

    VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo pipelineInfo = {};
    pipelineInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_CREATE_INFO;
    pipelineInfo.stageCount = (uint32_t)shaderStages.size();    
    pipelineInfo.pStages = shaderStages.data();                
    pipelineInfo.pVertexInputState = &vertexInputStage;        
    pipelineInfo.pInputAssemblyState = &inputAssemblyStage;     
    pipelineInfo.pViewportState = &viewportState;               
    pipelineInfo.pRasterizationState = &rasterizationStage;    
    pipelineInfo.pDepthStencilState = &depthStencilStage;      
    pipelineInfo.pMultisampleState = &multisamplingStage;      
    pipelineInfo.pColorBlendState = &colorBlendState;           
    pipelineInfo.pDynamicState = &dynamicStateCI;
    pipelineInfo.layout = pipelineLayout;                      
    pipelineInfo.renderPass = renderPass;                       
    pipelineInfo.subpass = 0;      
    pipelineInfo.stageCount = 1;

    if (vkCreateGraphicsPipelines(device.logicalDevice, VK_NULL_HANDLE, 1, &pipelineInfo, nullptr, &resultPipelineHandle) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Vulkan: Error while creating pipeline");
    }

    tools::LogMessage("Vulkan: Pipeline sucessfully initialized");

    for (VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo &shaderStageInfo : shaderStages) {
        vkDestroyShaderModule(device.logicalDevice, shaderStageInfo.module, nullptr);
    }

    return resultPipelineHandle;
}
```

first pass renderPassage

```
VkRenderPass MainRenderer::initShadowRenderPassage(const VKStr::Device &device)
{

    std::vector<VkAttachmentDescription> attachments;

    VkAttachmentDescription depthStencilAttachment = {};
    depthStencilAttachment.format = shadowPass_.depthFormat;
    depthStencilAttachment.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;                                
    depthStencilAttachment.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;                           
    depthStencilAttachment.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;                    
    depthStencilAttachment.stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;                
    depthStencilAttachment.stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;              
    depthStencilAttachment.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;                      
    depthStencilAttachment.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL; 
    attachments.push_back(depthStencilAttachment);

    VkAttachmentReference depthStencilAttachemntReference = {
        0,                                                           
        VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL             
    };

    VkSubpassDescription subpassDescription = {};
    subpassDescription.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
    subpassDescription.colorAttachmentCount = 0;  
    subpassDescription.pDepthStencilAttachment = &depthStencilAttachemntReference;         

    std::vector<VkSubpassDependency> dependencies = {
        {
            VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL,                                                      
            0,                                                                        
            VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT,                                     
            VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_EARLY_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT,                            
            VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT,
            VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT,
            VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT
        },
        {
            0,                                                                        
            VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL,                                                      
            VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_LATE_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT,                            
            VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT,                                     
            VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT,
            VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT,
            VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT
        }
    };


    VkRenderPassCreateInfo renderPassInfo = {};
    renderPassInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_CREATE_INFO;
    renderPassInfo.attachmentCount = 1;              
    renderPassInfo.pAttachments = attachments.data();                               
    renderPassInfo.subpassCount = 1;                                                
    renderPassInfo.pSubpasses = &subpassDescription;                                
    renderPassInfo.dependencyCount = (unsigned int)dependencies.size();            
    renderPassInfo.pDependencies = dependencies.data();                             

    VkRenderPass renderPass;
    if (vkCreateRenderPass(device.logicalDevice, &renderPassInfo, nullptr, &renderPass) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Vulkan: Failed to create render passage");
    }

    tools::LogMessage("Vulkan: Render passage successfully initialized");

    return renderPass;
}
```

first pass frameBuff

```
void MainRenderer::initShadowFrameBuffer(const VKStr::Device &device)
{
    this->shadowPass_.width = 4096;
    this->shadowPass_.height = 4096;

    VkImageCreateInfo image = {};
    image.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO;
    image.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
    image.extent.width = shadowPass_.width;
    image.extent.height = shadowPass_.height;
    image.extent.depth = 1;
    image.mipLevels = 1;
    image.arrayLayers = 1;
    image.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    image.tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL;
    image.format = this->shadowPass_.depthFormat;                                                           
    image.usage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT;     
    image.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_CONCURRENT;
    if (vkCreateImage(device.logicalDevice, &image, nullptr, &shadowPass_.depth.image) != VK_SUCCESS)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Vulkan: Error shadowImage create info");
    }

    VkMemoryAllocateInfo memAlloc{};
    memAlloc.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_INFO;
    VkMemoryRequirements memReqs;
    vkGetImageMemoryRequirements(device.logicalDevice, shadowPass_.depth.image, &memReqs);
    memAlloc.allocationSize = memReqs.size;
    memAlloc.memoryTypeIndex = GetMemoryTypeIndex(device.physicalDevice, memReqs.memoryTypeBits, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT);

    if (vkAllocateMemory(device.logicalDevice, &memAlloc, nullptr, &shadowPass_.depth.memory) != VK_SUCCESS)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Vulkan: Error Shadow AllocateMemory");
    }
    if (vkBindImageMemory(device.logicalDevice, shadowPass_.depth.image, shadowPass_.depth.memory, 0) != VK_SUCCESS)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Vulkan: Error shadow bindMemory");
    }

    VkImageViewCreateInfo depthStencilView = {};
    depthStencilView.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW_CREATE_INFO;
    depthStencilView.viewType = VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D;
    depthStencilView.format = this->shadowPass_.depthFormat;
    depthStencilView.subresourceRange = {};
    depthStencilView.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_DEPTH_BIT;
    depthStencilView.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
    depthStencilView.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
    depthStencilView.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    depthStencilView.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;
    depthStencilView.image = shadowPass_.depth.image;

    if (vkCreateImageView(device.logicalDevice, &depthStencilView, nullptr, &shadowPass_.depth.view) != VK_SUCCESS)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Vulkan: Error shadow createImageView");
    }


    VkFramebufferCreateInfo fbufCreateInfo = {};
    fbufCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_FRAMEBUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
    fbufCreateInfo.renderPass = shadowPass_.renderPass;
    fbufCreateInfo.attachmentCount = 1;
    fbufCreateInfo.pAttachments = &shadowPass_.depth.view;
    fbufCreateInfo.width = shadowPass_.width;
    fbufCreateInfo.height = shadowPass_.height;
    fbufCreateInfo.layers = 1;

    if (vkCreateFramebuffer(device.logicalDevice, &fbufCreateInfo, nullptr, &shadowPass_.frameBuffer) != VK_SUCCESS)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Vulkan: Error shadow frameBuffer");
    }

    VkSamplerCreateInfo sampler = {};
    sampler.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SAMPLER_CREATE_INFO;
    sampler.magFilter = VK_FILTER_LINEAR;
    sampler.minFilter = VK_FILTER_LINEAR;
    sampler.mipmapMode = VK_SAMPLER_MIPMAP_MODE_LINEAR;
    sampler.addressModeU = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_CLAMP_TO_EDGE;
    sampler.addressModeV = sampler.addressModeU;
    sampler.addressModeW = sampler.addressModeU;
    sampler.mipLodBias = 0.0f;
    sampler.maxAnisotropy = 1.0f;
    sampler.minLod = 0.0f;
    sampler.maxLod = 1.0f;
    sampler.borderColor = VK_BORDER_COLOR_FLOAT_OPAQUE_WHITE;

    if (vkCreateSampler(device.logicalDevice, &sampler, nullptr, &shadowPass_.depthSampler) != VK_SUCCESS)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Vulkan: Error Shadow createSampler");
    }

}
```

commandBuff

```
void MainRenderer::PrepareDrawCommands(std::vector<VkCommandBuffer> commandBuffers, VkRenderPass renderPass, std::vector<VkPipelineLayout> pipelineLayout, VkDescriptorSet descriptorSetMain, VkDescriptorSet descriptorSetInfo, VkDescriptorSet descriptorSetVLight, const VKStr::Swapchain & swapchain, const std::vector<VKStr::Primitive>& primitives)
{
    VkCommandBufferBeginInfo cmdBufInfo = {};
    cmdBufInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;
    cmdBufInfo.flags = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_SIMULTANEOUS_USE_BIT;
    cmdBufInfo.pNext = nullptr;

    std::vector<VkClearValue> clearValues(2);
    clearValues[0].color = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    clearValues[1].depthStencil.depth = 1.0f;
    clearValues[1].depthStencil.stencil = 0;

    std::vector<VkClearValue> clearValuesShadow(1);
    clearValuesShadow[0].depthStencil = { 1.0f, 0 };
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < commandBuffers.size(); ++i)
    {
        VkRenderPassBeginInfo renderPassBeginInfo = {};
        vkBeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffers[i], &cmdBufInfo);
        if (ShadowRender)
        {

            renderPassBeginInfo = {};
            renderPassBeginInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO;
            renderPassBeginInfo.pNext = nullptr;
            renderPassBeginInfo.renderPass = this->shadowPass_.renderPass;
            renderPassBeginInfo.renderArea.offset.x = 0;
            renderPassBeginInfo.renderArea.offset.y = 0;
            renderPassBeginInfo.renderArea.extent.width = this->shadowPass_.width;
            renderPassBeginInfo.renderArea.extent.height = this->shadowPass_.height;
            renderPassBeginInfo.clearValueCount = clearValuesShadow.size();
            renderPassBeginInfo.pClearValues = clearValuesShadow.data();

            renderPassBeginInfo.framebuffer = this->shadowPass_.frameBuffer;

            vkCmdBeginRenderPass(commandBuffers[i], &renderPassBeginInfo, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);

            vkCmdSetDepthBias(
                commandBuffers[i],
                1.25f,
                0.0f,
                1.75f);

            if (!primitives.empty()) {
                for (unsigned int primitiveIndex = 0; primitiveIndex < primitives.size(); primitiveIndex++)
                {
                    vkCmdBindPipeline(commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, this->pipelines_[3]);

                    std::vector<uint32_t> dynamicOffsets = {
                        primitiveIndex * static_cast<uint32_t>(this->device_.GetDynamicAlignment<glm::mat4>())
                    };

                    if (primitives_[primitiveIndex].pipelineIndex == AREAN_SHADER_T_BASE)
                    {
                        std::vector<VkDescriptorSet> descriptorSets = {
                        this->descriptorSetShadow_
                        };


                        vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(
                            commandBuffers[i],
                            VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS,
                            pipelineLayout[2],
                            0,
                            (uint32_t)descriptorSets.size(),
                            descriptorSets.data(),
                            (uint32_t)dynamicOffsets.size(),
                            dynamicOffsets.data());


                        if (primitives[primitiveIndex].drawIndexed && primitives[primitiveIndex].indexBuffer.count > 0) {

                            VkDeviceSize offsets[1] = { 0 };
                            vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(commandBuffers[i], 0, 1, &(primitives[primitiveIndex].vertexBuffer.vkBuffer), offsets);


                            vkCmdBindIndexBuffer(commandBuffers[i], primitives[primitiveIndex].indexBuffer.vkBuffer, 0, VK_INDEX_TYPE_UINT32);


                            vkCmdDrawIndexed(commandBuffers[i], primitives[primitiveIndex].indexBuffer.count, 1, 0, 0, 0);
                        }

                        else {
                            VkDeviceSize offsets[1] = { 0 };
                            vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(commandBuffers[i], 0, 1, &(primitives[primitiveIndex].vertexBuffer.vkBuffer), offsets);

                            vkCmdDraw(commandBuffers[i], primitives[primitiveIndex].vertexBuffer.count, 1, 0, 0);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

            vkCmdEndRenderPass(commandBuffers[i]);

        }

    /*VkImageSubresourceRange imageRes = {}; //i try it, but not affect.
            imageRes.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_DEPTH_BIT;
            imageRes.baseMipLevel = 0;
            imageRes.levelCount = 1;
            imageRes.baseArrayLayer = 0;
            imageRes.layerCount = 1;

            VkImageMemoryBarrier imageMemoryBarrier = {};
                imageMemoryBarrier.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
                imageMemoryBarrier.pNext = NULL;
                imageMemoryBarrier.image = this->shadowPass_.depth.image;
                imageMemoryBarrier.subresourceRange = imageRes;
                imageMemoryBarrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
                imageMemoryBarrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT;
                imageMemoryBarrier.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
                imageMemoryBarrier.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;


                vkCmdPipelineBarrier(commandBuffers[i],
                    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_EARLY_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT |
                    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_LATE_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT, // srcStageMask
                    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT, // dstStageMask
                    0,
                    0, nullptr,
                    0, nullptr,
                    1, // imageMemoryBarrierCount
                    &imageMemoryBarrier // pImageMemoryBarriers
                    );*/


            renderPassBeginInfo = {};
            renderPassBeginInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO;
            renderPassBeginInfo.pNext = nullptr;
            renderPassBeginInfo.renderPass = renderPass;
            renderPassBeginInfo.renderArea.offset.x = 0;
            renderPassBeginInfo.renderArea.offset.y = 0;
            renderPassBeginInfo.renderArea.extent.width = swapchain.imageExtent.width;
            renderPassBeginInfo.renderArea.extent.height = swapchain.imageExtent.height;
            renderPassBeginInfo.clearValueCount = (uint32_t)clearValues.size();
            renderPassBeginInfo.pClearValues = clearValues.data();  
            renderPassBeginInfo.framebuffer = swapchain.framebuffers[i];

            vkCmdBeginRenderPass(commandBuffers[i], &renderPassBeginInfo, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);

            /*2 pass*/
    }
}
```

Comment: This is hard to debug without a proper working stand-alone application. My first steps would be checking if there are any validation layer messages and then run the application through RenderDoc. Esp. RenderDoc should help you see what is actually written to your buffers and may help you rule out basic faults like wrong face winding etc.

Comment: I did not know about the existence of such a program, although I have already checked it in other ways. I will test further, maybe the program will tell you exactly where the problem may be.

Comment: The only thing that worries me is that the vertex shader returns zeros. I don't have a fragment shader, so maybe it should? https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_nbFdX3k16pd_81SDTubldBidtQ-8G37